# Why do GCP Pub/Sub messages have duplicated message_id and publish_time values?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm receiving messages from a pub/sub push subscription.

Here's the payload of one such message in raw bytes:

```
REQUEST_BODY b'{"message":{"attributes":{"one":"two"},"data":"InN0dWZmIg==","messageId":"5481363137518973","message_id":"5481363137518973","publishTime":"2022-08-24T16:39:11.08Z","publish_time":"2022-08-24T16:39:11.08Z"},"subscription":"projects/my-project/subscriptions/my-subscription-name"}\n'
```

Notice that in the message there are two duplicated values:

- `messageId` vs `message_id`
- `publishTime` vs `publish_time`

Now, I'm aware that some languages and styles prefer snake versus camel cases, and I'm not getting into what's *right*...

But objectively there should be only one for transmission over the wire, rather than sending BOTH!

I don't care which gets used, but I do care that I'm getting charged for this bandwidth!!

Why does GCP do this, and can I turn it off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is for backward compatibility. I think message_id was introduced earlier and then they changed it to messageId. In order to not break the existing code that someone may have written using message_id, they left it there and added messageId. Same thing applied to publishTime.

AFAIK you cannot turn it off.

Did some research on pricing. If I understand it correctly, you are not charged for Egress from pub/sub if your subscriber is in the same region as your pub/sub topic.

I am not sure about Throughput cost. Does it charge for the entire message body including the attributes added by Google or just for the data/attributes part (that you published)? I guess, someone from Google can answer that.

Thanks @KamalAboul-Hosn. I also found this excerpt on Pub/Sub pricing page on Google:

> The data volume of a message is the sum of the sizes of the following
> message attributes:
>
> - The number of bytes in the encoded message body string
> - For each attribute, the size of the key and its value
> - 20 bytes for the timestamp
> - The size of the message_id string
> - The size of additional optional fields, such as those associated with early access and other restricted-access APIs.

Comment: Sigh. OK, that's useful to know. so assuming they deprecate it at some point I'll use the camelCase variant and ignore anything snaky. Thanks!

Comment: One would not get charged twice in terms of Pub/Sub throughput costs for the extra fields. The calculation for message size happens before the attributes are duplicated for backwards compatibility.